# Автоинкремент в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица `orders` с полями `order_id (bigint), value (text)`.

Как у столбца `id` можно сделать автоинкремент следующего вида: `0000001, 0000002 .... 0000010 .... 0001234 ...` и тд?

Пробовал так, но пропадают все нули:

```
order_id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0000001 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правилам математики числа `00001` и `1` - это одно и то же самое число `1`. Собственно, `bigint` это всегда фиксированные 8 байт данных.

Если вам нужны лидирующие нули для какой-либо цели - вы должны преобразовывать число в текст и добавлять нули до нужной длинны строки сами.

В частности, например на SQL:

```
select lpad(cast(order_id as text), 5, '0') from orders;
```

Comment: @FredPerry можно добавить в таблицу `orders` колонку `number` и генерировать её значение так, как предложил Мелкий (в DEFAULT)

Comment: неа, в default не получится. default не может ссылаться на другие поля. Тут или before insert/update триггер или generated column (pg12+) если хотеть добавить именно в эту таблицу.

Comment: тогда можно создать секвенс и `number varchar(10) DEFAULT lpad(cast(currval('order_seq'::regclass) as text), 5, '0')`

Comment: но очень внимательно подумать, стоит ли для задачи *вывода* данных ломать схему хранения.